# Error posting API to API Manager (v1.10.0) from GREG (v5.1.0)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-governance-registry

I have followed the instructions laid out in the documentation for GREG (5.1.0) to configure GREG to publish APIs to an external API Manager (1.10.0). I followed the configuration updates (modified the LifeCycle in the configuration.xml) and promoted a REST API. Unfortunately, when I promote the API to Production I don't receive any feedback in the GREG Publisher UI, the API is not imported into API Manager, and I receive the following errors in the GREG logs:

*Note: I've scrubbed these logs for potentially sensitive information.*

```
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,432] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  overview_name  :  xxxxxxxxxxxx
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,451] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  interface_transports  :  https
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,454] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  uritemplate_httpVerb  :  get
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,454] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  interface_swagger  :  /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/api-docs/1.0.0/xxxxxxxxx
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,454] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  contacts_entry  :  Technical Owner: xxxxxxxxx
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,455] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  overview_endpointURL  :  http://xxxxxxxx/
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,456] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  uritemplate_authType  :  None
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,457] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  overview_description  :  xxxxxxxxx
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,457] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  overview_context  :  /xxxxxxxx/
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,457] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  overview_version  :  0.0.4
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,460] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  uritemplate_urlPattern  :  /xxxxxx/{id}.xml
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,460] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  overview_provider  :  admin
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,460] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  endpoints_entry  :  Prod:https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/
[2016-02-01 15:33:34,460] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.executors.apistore.RestServiceToAPIExecutor} -  security_authenticationType  :  None
```

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/klousiaj/ff6d9014a2b5381d80c3) with the logs for both API Manager and GREG.

Comment: could you post the complete error log by removing the sensitivity data?

Comment: I made an edit to include a link to a gist with both AM and GREG log files.

Comment: could you post the execution element for publish event in  ServiceLifeCycle.xml as well?

Comment: I've added a new file snippet to the above referenced gist.

Comment: @lakshman has there been any update on this? I still haven't been able to get it working.